# What is the difference between the second argument of ToString and its option FormatType?

Tags: string-manipulation, options, optional-arguments

Is there any real difference between `ToString[expr, form]` and `ToString[expr, FormatType→form]`?

In all my examples, they seem to be the same.  I would like to know why there are both possibilities of controlling the output.  Does anyone know if there is a use for using both the second argument and the option at the same time?

Comment: Presumably the `Option` form is the actual implementation and the second argument version unravels to it. Consider: `SetOptions[ToString, FormatType -> CForm]` (note that this causes some funky output effects. Reset it by replacing `CForm` with `OutputForm`). Although the second argument does seem to take precedence over the option version. Good find.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I tried `SetOptions[ToString, FormatType -> CForm]`, but nothing funky happened.  `ToString` just converts everything to `CForm` normally  (Mathematica 10.3 Mac OS X 10.10).  Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: The funkiness I found was in things like the output labels and presumably that will propagate through anywhere a bare `ToString` is used. Just a preemptive warning to anyone trying that and later being confused as to why things are displaying differently from expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference between using a secong argument which is a member of `$PrintForms` and using the option `FormatType`.  If the second argument is used, the option value is ignored.

The reason both exist is historical.  In V1 and V2, `ToString` had no second argument, and its options were documented to be equal to that of `OpenAppend`.  In V3, the second argument was added.  This is partly because it was by far the most important option that could be given to `ToString`, and also that `OpenAppend` started having options that really didn't make sense for `ToString` (e.g., BinaryFormat).  While the documentation continued to state for many versions that it could take all the options of `OpenAppend`, all the "new" options were silently ignored.

[I busted out a copy of The Mathematica Book, 2nd Edition, just to make sure my historical reconstruction was correct. :)]

Comment: That's interesting!  I should go to a library and have a look at some of the earlier editions of The Mathematica Book.  It might be fun to see how Mathematica has evolved over the years.